# Samsung galaxy J1 dialing pad shortcut

Tags: samsung-galaxy-j1

Is there a way to go straight from the home screen using a shortcut, directly to the dialing pad/phone keypad, without first going through phone > keypad ?

Ideally I'd like this shortcut to be in the shortcut bar at the bottom of the home screen rather than one of the home 'pages'.

Comment: You can try [Quick short cut maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut). Scroll through the system app activities and of you find the activity that launches keypad, simply create a shortcut and place wherever you want. Let me know if it works to post as an answer